# Reading backend data, ISO format date

Tags: javascript

I get data from the backend that look like that

`start: '2022-10-22T00:00:00Z, end: '2022-10-26T00:00:00Z`

regarding the discount of a product. So that basically means that the product is discounted until `25.10.22 until 23.59`, right? Thought it would be until `26.10.22 until 23.59` and got a bit confused. Thank you!

Comment: > So that basically means that the product is discounted until 25.10.22 until 23.59, right?

Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's precisely what it is.

from *2022-10-22@12am* to *2022-10-26@12am*

You should use the provided date as is, but I suggest you convert it first to milliseconds before comparing.

There are plenty of well-maintained packages out there that can do the work for you, be it composer or npm, where you'll just have to supply the dates.